# wildfly ejb1.1 deployment migration from jboss as 4.0.5 to wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, migration, wildfly-8

I have an javaee application already running on jboss 4.0.5 version i want to migrate it on wildfly, in this application i am using ejb1.1,  how do i migrate ejb1.1 to wildfly?

i checked on some site and i found that by renaming jboss.xml to jboss-ejb3.xml it will work but i am not able to make it run by doing doing so.

i am getting run time exception that receive time out error while looking up for beans from context :

```
Context itsInitialContext;
String factory = "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory";
String prefixes = "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces";
String url = "localhost";

Hashtable envmap = new Hashtable();
envmap.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, factory );
envmap.put( Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, prefixes );
envmap.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, url );

//get naming context...
itsInitialContext = new InitialContext(envmap);

Object objref = itsInitialContext.lookup(beanService.getBeanName());
```

-- This line throwing error that revceive time out....

Please help.....

Thanks in advance.